# Make current page highlighted and have a different hover color for other items

Tags: css

I am making a menu bar, and I know how to get the hover color to change, what I am having trouble with is making it so that the `.current` menu item I had a red background, and the hover `background-color` to be american flag blue. Once I add the code for the hover it overrides the red color for some reason.

Here is the html

```
<div id="nav_menu">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="aircraft.html">Aircraft</a></li>
            <li><a href="briefing.html">Briefing</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
```

here is all the css for these

```
#nav_menu    { 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
#nav_menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav_menu li a.current {
    background-color: #BF0A30;
}
#nav_menu a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:black;
    height: 100%;
}
#nav_menu a:hover {
    opacity: 0.85;
    background-color:#009;
    color:#fff;
}

ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#nav_menu li a.current` should be `#nav_menu li.current`, since your `current` class is on the `li` element of your HTML.

Also, you need to remove the white background-color on `#nav_menu a`, because that sits right on top of `li`, so you cant see the red below.

```css
#nav_menu    { 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
#nav_menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav_menu li.current {
    background-color: #BF0A30;
    
}
#nav_menu a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    height: 100%;
}
#nav_menu a:hover {
    opacity: 0.85;
    background-color:#009;
    color:#fff;
}

ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav_menu li.current a {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_menu">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="aircraft.html">Aircraft</a></li>
            <li><a href="briefing.html">Briefing</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: So this works thank you for that, now I am having a problem getting the text color to be white for li.current, seems that whatever I change it does not effect that. The black on red is too difficult too read. Do you happen to have an idea for that??

Comment: Just use `#nav_menu li.current a {color: white;}` -- I edited the snippet above for a working example. If this answer resolved your issue, please accept/upvote so that others can benefit as well. Best, Josh

Answer (score 0):

The `.current` class is applied to the `li` element in your case, that's why your CSS rules don't work. Changing the selector for that rule to `#nav_menu li.current a` will fix that:

```css
#nav_menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

#nav_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}



#nav_menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
}



#nav_menu a:hover {
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #009;
  color: #fff;
}

#nav_menu li.current a {
  background-color: #BF0A30;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="aircraft.html">Aircraft</a></li>
      <li><a href="briefing.html">Briefing</a></li>
      <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, I knew it had to do with the a I just couldn't figure out how to change it thanks alot.